# Jquery Wait/Page Loading

Tags: jquery, loading, wait

This question is more than just a 'wait' dialogue, I basically have a search service which can take several seconds to load. So you would start on a search form, and click search and then this will go to another page (which can take several seconds to load e.g. come from the server).  I don't want to make this an ajax call, I do want it to go from page A to page B however I would like to be able to implement a loading page until the second page has come back from server.  Nearest I have found is on

http://www.holidayautos.co.uk

Where user waits on the first page until the second is ready, could anyone advise on using jquery the best way of doing this?

Comment: I have to suggest that I think you're doing it wrong. I would investigate further how they're doing their page.

Answer (score 2):

First, show your "loading" overlay.

Then create a hidden Iframe with an "onload" event and point it to the new page. When the onload fires, show the Iframe and hide your overlay.

This is the only way you can tell another page has "loaded" while maintaining control over the current page.

Comment: I think this aproach is right, however, I will use a hidden div instead of a iframe, and you can format it with CSS

Comment: How are you going to load the content WITHOUT AJAX in a DIV?

Comment: The div will only have your loading animation, the new content will be display when you load your new page... in other words, when you fire the event, you will change the visivilty of the div from hidden to block or whatever.... and the loading will show... then when the new page is load it will disapear... changing the visivility of a div on the fly is not ajax

Comment: All animation will stop as soon as the new page is requested. This includes animated GIFs.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the BlockUI plugin.  It will allow you to put an overlay over a page with a message on an event.  Simply attach BlockUI to the form.submit event and you should be all set.

http://jquery.malsup.com/block/

Comment: It simply goes to it when there's content for the browser to display.  Your results page script ought to be designed so it doesn't start sending output until the search is complete though.